# identifying which item is clicked in a multi level list using jquery

Tags: jquery, list

my html looks like this

```
<div class="row1">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row2">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row3">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here's my jquery to get the index of clicked item:

```
$('li').click(function(){
 var ind = $(this).index();
 alert(ind);
});
```

This alerts the index of item clicked.  However, items 1 of row1, row2 and row3 have the same index.  Same with item2 and item3.  This, I can understand because it belongs to different ul.  Am thinking of creating different click listeners for 3 ul.  But am thinking whether you guys have a better idea to create one listener for all that would give continous index number for all items.

thanks.

Comment: You could take the li element and look for its div parent, then use the parent's class or another attribute to determine its index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of the list of `<li>` elements and then use that to determine the index:

```
var $all_lis = $('li');

$all_lis.on('click', function() {
  var index = $all_lis.index(this);
  alert(index);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ovolon/1/)

The first item will give `0`, the last item will give `8` (i.e. 9th item).

Comment: this actually works.  However, I am also using lis for my navigation bars and other images on the header so the index on this list starts with number 20.  Is there a way to force the start index of this lis to 0 or 1?  so that if ever i need to change the other list in the header i won't be changing the jquery code as well.  many thanks Jack

Comment: @SaintDee Then you should anchor the selector, i.e. `$all_lis = $('#some_id li')`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get index of selected `ul` element? Try this:

`var parentInd = $(this).parent().parent().index();`

Comment: No, OP wants to get the continuous index of the `<li>` pressed, i.e. last item should be index 8 (9th item).

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the callback function is just what you want, the clicked item.

Comment: I do think OP is aware of that :) it's about finding out the position within the list of items.